# How to create an encrypted connection with FTPS

Tags: iis, ssl, ftp, ftps

I have to exchange some file via FTPS... I have created a really simple FTP server on IIS where I enable anonymous access and SSL is required. Everything works but I have some doubt about security.. 
Here the code:

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(fileUri) as FtpWebRequest;
ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
```

I have enabled SSL but for example I expeceted that credentials was required. It look likes anonymous access are possible even if I am using SSL!! Is it correct?

A second question...  `fileUri = ftp://127.0.0.1/blablabla...`.. Does not should be  `ftps://`? Ok, I set fileUri equal to  `ftp://` but I expected that it raised an exception... everything works instead..

Another thing, I expected to have a certificate on client side.. but I do not understand how to set it in a ftp request. I am worried because i think that everything is working just because Server an Client are matching. Am I wrong?

Tnak you
Thank you

Comment: That's entirely up to your FTP server.

Comment: You mean that anonymous access are possible even if Im using SSL? It depends just on the configuration on the server?

Comment: Yes; SSL just means that the connection is encrypted.

Comment: And what about other two questions?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.clientcertificates

Comment: I had already seen it... but it does not clarify my doubt... so forget my third answer.. I will do a test with a remote machine.. and I will understand surely... what about the second one?